# Generating access Token with loginRedirect in Azure AD B2C portal

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

I am generating token using Azure AD B2C Portal. When I am using loginPopup method then I can generate Token successfully but got `undefined` while using loginRedirect.

here's the code:

```
clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
        this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority, 
        function (errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
            // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
        }
);

public login(): void {
       var _this = this;
       // loginRedirect loginPopup
        this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
            _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                function (accessToken: any) {
                    _this.access_token = accessToken;
                }, function (error: any) {
                    _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                        function (accessToken: any) {
                            _this.access_token = accessToken;
                        }, function (error: any) {
                            bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                        });
                })
        }, function (error: any) {
            bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });
        console.log(`access token service file ${_this.access_token}`);
    }
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing? is it Scope issue OR callback method issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [reference](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/devApps/VanillaJSTestApp/index_LoginRedirect.html). By this I was able to achieve access token. you will get it in `sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken')`.

Comment: I found this in msal.nonce.idtoken

Comment: This is an idtoken, not an access token.

Answer (score -1):

For `loginRedirect` you add your handler code of the response in `// Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup` block.

```
clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
        this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority, 
        function (errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
            // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
            // perform your logic HERE! :)
        }
);

public login(){
    this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
}
```

Comment: The above does  not get called after a loginredirect in an Angular 4 application.

Comment: @ShailenSukul it does for me!  Please see this sample app [NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal](https://github.com/spottedmahn/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/master/ClientApp/app/services/authentication.service.ts)